# Unicode / Russian characters and Win32 api [C++]

Tags: c++, unicode, winapi

I'm trying to catch Russian characters with **GetAsyncKeyState()** win32 api, but apparently it doesn't seem to work except with English.

Any idea??

CODE:

```
                for(unsigned char c = 1; c < 255; c++){
                        SHORT rv = GetAsyncKeyState(c);
                    if(rv & 1){ // on press button down
                        string out = "";
                        if(c == 1)
                                out = "[LMOUSE]"; // mouse left
...
```

Comment: well... you could use the message system to get actual characters... I think functions like the one in your question are more for key states... but not too sure

Comment: Please post more of your code. Also, [GetAsyncKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) is probably not the best choice to *catch* Cyrillic characters, since it deals with [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead of actual characters.

Comment: some code added, this is how I try to get keys, I can only get English chars...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetAsyncKeyState() lets you inspect *virtual* keys.  A virtual key doesn't become a Russian glyph until the WM_KEYDOWN message is processed by Windows through TranslateMessage(), turning that message into a WM_CHAR based on the current keyboard layout.

Mapping a glyph back to a virtual key is possible with VkKeyScanEx().  This can get rapidly very complicated if the glyph is generated by dead keys.  In other words, requiring more than one keystroke.  No idea what a Russian keyboard layout looks like, ymmv.

Comment: I see, so how do I manually turn a virtual key number using the TranslateMessage() to a Unicode character?